# Как находить в базе данных определенный продукт?

Tags: python, sqlite

Ребят, такой вопрос, у меня есть таблица в базе данных, называется product в ней есть:

```
name = 'Название продукта'
calories = 'количество калорий в продукте'
protein = 'Количество белка в продукте'
fats = 'количество жира в продукте'
carbohydrates = 'количество углеводов в продукте'
```

Например:
Имя = Рис, калорий = 300, белка = 10, жира = 2, углеводов = 70
Имя = Гречка, калорий = 320, белка = 16, жира = 1, углеводов = 65

Пользователь вводит Рис и хочет получить значение калорий, белка, жира и углеводов в Рисе, в базе он находится под именем Рис, а вдруг пользователь введет Риса, Руса или еще как то ошибется, то в базе ничего не найдется.
Подскажите как можно примерно реализовать, чтобы в базе отыскивалось максимально похожие имя. Я знаю про нечеткое сравнение строк, но как это с базой связать не знаю, может в sqlite есть запрос какой то специальный, но я ничего не нашел

Comment: Если продуктов не 100500, то можно их все прочитать в питон и там уже через `fuzzywuzzy` какой-нибудь нечётко искать. Прямо в базе сложно будет, думаю, сделать нечёткий поиск. Хотя можно делать `like` и заменять одну-две... буквы на `%`. И потом из того, что выбралось уже искать ближайшее, если не хочется все названия выкачивать.

Comment: @CrazyElf это утопия. Если пользователь введёт рус вместо рис, и надо ему показать рис... Приложение без триграм индекса в базе будет жутко лагать.

Comment: можно выгружать из базы весь список имен продуктов, с помощью fuzzywuzzy искать, и наиболее подходящий уже выгружать из базы, я так и хотел сначала сделать, но подумал, что он сильно будет тормозить весь процесс и думал может что по гуманнее есть

Comment: @Tesla можно. Но с ростом числа продуктов такой алгоритм будет всё больше "тормозить". Когда это приблизится например к 1000, вы будете ждать десятки секунд. Когда к 10000 - до часа. Не думаю, что Вас это устроит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) расширение для SQLite

Из минусов - функция [trigram](https://habr.com/ru/post/78566/) [индекса](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/13/pgtrgm) в нём экспериментальная.

Я бы на Вашем месте присмотрелся к [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/pgtrgm.html).

Comment: Немного не понял, вы имеете ввиду сметь бд на PostgreSQL.? Там легче это реализовать?

Comment: @Tesla да, это другая СУБД, в которой trigram index  уже очень давно реализован и работает. Вы просто создаёте такой индекс, и в самом SQL запросе пишете что то типа similar(значение), на выходе получаете список результатов еще и со степенью похожести на запрос.